# Objective-c Check file size from URL without downloading

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to check the size of file from a URL. I get the file size perfectly when downloading file with AFNetworking.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                            // Success Callback

                                                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                            // Failure Callback

                                                                        }];
```

and get file size in another block

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    }];
```

But i need to check file size before initiating download request, so that i can prompt to user. I have also tried another method

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lasp.colorado.edu/home/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/suncombo1.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"original = %d", [data length]);
```

But it blocks the UI, coz it download all data to calculate its size.
Is there any way to check file size before downloading? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the server supports it you can make a request to just get the headers (`HEAD`, as opposed to `GET`) without the actual data payload and this should include the `Content-Length`.

If you can't do that then you need to start the download and use `expectedContentLength` of the `NSURLResponse`.

---

Basically, create an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest` and call `setHTTPMethod:` with the `method` parameter set to `@"HEAD"` (to replace the default which is `GET`). Then send that to the server as you currently request for the full set of data (same URL).

Comment: Thanks Wain for reply, i am actually making request object as: 
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:zipURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
I could not find any attribute/method to get headers.

Comment: Can you be more specific with getting headers?

Comment: @BhavikKama, please be more specific with your question, or create a new question if you have additional questions over the above

Answer (score 7):

here is the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:candidateURL];
                    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

                    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
                    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Content-lent: %lld", [operation.response expectedContentLength]);

                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                     }];
```

Comment: don't forget [operation start]; :)

Comment: not needed. I have created an NSOperationQueue, so when I add operation to it, it will started implicitly. `[operationQueue addOperation:operation];`