# single ProgressView for multiple file(s) download task

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, nsurlrequest

I am **Not** Using: ASIHTTPRequest, AFNetworking, RestKit.

I have multiple images/files to be downloaded via **Asynchronous** call to web service for downloading.

I am showing SVProgressHUD (**Activity Indicator**, **NOT** **Bar**) during the download process.

Till this point, everything works fine.

Now, my client wants me to show the single Progress**Bar** on the view for file(s) being downloaded, so as to make user aware about the approximate time it would take.

**Problem:** How can I get consolidated time/size for the files being downloaded **Asynchronously**.

I am open for using any API that serves the purpose. I hope I am making sense, here.

Hard Time. Any Hints?

Comment: are you using NSURLConnection ?

Comment: Same issue I am finding solution for. Let me know what approach you applied for this problem.

Comment: We are talking about 2000+ files here. may be much more that.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSProgress_Class/index.html), it's not a UIKit class but will allow you to crate multiple instances of NSProgress (one for each activity) and then get a combined progress value which you can hook up to your UI.

There a good write up about it here with examples:
http://oleb.net/blog/2014/03/nsprogress/

You basically use KVO to read the progress value and then update your UI element i.e. progress bar.

Comment: I will look into it & let you know how it goes... Thanks.

Comment: @Camsoft Nice suggestion. Any working tutorial you know of, for `NSProgress` OR any Github Project?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get length of all files with "head" request, then just calculate it yourself:
amount of data downloaded/total-data-length.

This post will help you to get total content length: [Objective-c Check file size from URL without downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632193/objective-c-check-file-size-from-url-without-downloading)

Other option - start downloading each file in separate thread and use shared variable to get consolidated time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not getting the "Head" request. Can you explain that in details? Do you mean to say having a separate webservice just for the getting number of total byte receivable?

Comment: Also, wouldn't that consume too much time for getting the "head" for each file? We are talking about more than 2000 or so files.

Comment: It might take a while, but if you download many files, it would be relatively short.

Comment: Do you have any example for the "Other Option" -- You have mentioned in your answer, as I am not so familiar with multithreading. Thanks for the help.