# How to know PDF file size before opened by UIWebview on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

Is that possible? Maybe there is some PDF api can get some information without downloading the whole PDF file?

Comment: you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632193/objective-c-check-file-size-from-url-without-downloading

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLSession` to request for the content length of the remote file. This can be done by setting the `request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"`

This method gets the file size for the specified `remoteFileURL`

```
func getRemoteFileSize(remoteFileURL : String) -> Int64{

    var contentLength: Int64 = NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown

    if let remoteURL = NSURL(string: remoteFileURL) {

        // Create a semaphore to wait for NSURLSession's dataTask to complete
        // before returning from function
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: remoteURL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,
                                                                       completionHandler:
            { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            contentLength = response?.expectedContentLength ?? NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown

            //Signal the semaphore to continue execution
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        })
        session.resume()

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }

    print("File size is \(contentLength)")
    return contentLength
}
```

***Please note*** : This method should be called on some other thread as this blocks the thread it's called on.

For e.g. :

**Method call**

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) {

    self.getRemoteFileSize("https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/apple-logo.jpg")
}
```

Comment: @Gon : Did this work for you? If you need any additional details let me know.