# Is it possible to get the size of an entire folder in a URL?

Tags: ios, url, nsurlrequest

I have an url with a entire folder to download but I would like to get the size of it, or at least calculate it before to download it.
I ask that question, because when I tap directly the url in the web, I can see that there is all the files, and all the files inside that folder : 
[image]

I tried with that, but it is only for a file, and if you do it in a folder, you only get the ridiculous size of the folder in bytes instead of the entire folder with all files.
[StackOverflow get size only for a url file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632193/objective-c-check-file-size-from-url-without-downloading)

Is there any way to get it, calculate it, or enumerating all files of the folder to get the HEAD ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know if the server supports [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)?

Answer (score 0):

That page is generated for you by the server as an html page, hence why you are able to see it in the browser. If you are working with this in a native app there are a couple options you can consider;

1. Parse the HTML document on the device. This approach is potentially quite flaky but you can get all the file/directory names available to you. Once you have built a list of all the file paths you can then perform all of the HEAD requests you need.
2. Write a server-side script in something like PHP which will provide you the size of the directory that you are wanting to retrieve. This will be much more effective than the first approach as you can do it in one request rather than needing to make a load of HEAD requests and sum up the size on the device. [An example of how you might do this](http://www.barattalo.it/coding/calculate-dir-size-recursively/).

Comment: Hello! I tried the first option, but it is too slow, it takes me the same time to do this, than download the entire folder...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to add a server-side script that intercepts "file not found" errors and if it matches the pattern "foldername.zip", recursively zips the corresponding folder and returns the result, or for a head request, recursively computes the size and returns it (crude worst-case size estimate).  The details of unknown file handling differ from server to server.

There is at least one security caveat with this approach.  You should probably call realname() on the path to sanitize it, then check that path against a list of approved prefixes to ensure that it is within the web root directory (and not, for example, /etc).